# WP7.1 (7.5) Application Bar icons are a "X"?

Tags: windows, default, windows-phone

When I include my Application Bar's icon URIs, I have them in the folder...but it still shows the default "X" icon instead of mine. Here is my code:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
    <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True">
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/help.png" Text="Help"/>
        <shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
            <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="about"/>
        </shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
    </shell:ApplicationBar>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
```

The default icon it shows is:

[image: Default Image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pay attention to how to compile the project. In particular check that the icon to include has this property:
**Build Action: Content**